# Print() does not work in 'for' loop with zip()

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I just received an email with quite a nice explaining Python Web Scraping with the lxml library so I want to test the result. I tried to print something in 'for info in zip(titles, prices, tags, total_platforms):' but I'm not able to print inside this function or even type(object). Resp dictionary doesn't save the data, debugger in Pycharm just skipped this block. I tried to print output but it showed me that it is empty. Could anyone explain me this situation?

```
import requests
import lxml.html

html = requests.get('https://store.steampowered.com/explore/new/')
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html.content)

new_releases = doc.xpath('//div[@id="tab_newreleases_content"]')[0]

titles = new_releases.xpath('.//div[@class="tab_item_name"]/text()')
prices = new_releases.xpath('.//div[@class="discount_final_price"]/text()')

tags = [tag.text_content() for tag in new_releases.xpath('.//div[@class="tab_item_top_tags"]')]
tags = [tag.split(', ') for tag in tags]

platforms_div = new_releases.xpath('.//div[@class="tab_item_details"]')
total_platforms = []

for game in platforms_div:
    temp = game.xpath('.//span[contains(@class, "platform_img")]')
    platforms = [t.get('class').split(' ')[-1] for t in temp]
    if 'hmd_separator' in platforms:
        platforms.remove('hmd_separator')
    total_platforms.append(platforms)
output = []
for info in zip(titles,prices, tags, total_platforms):
    resp = {}
    resp['title'] = info[0]
    resp['price'] = info[1]
    resp['tags'] = info[2]
    resp['platforms'] = info[3]
    output.append(resp)
```

src: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/an-intro-to-web-scraping-with-lxml-and-python-b02b7a3f3098

Comment: If any of those lists are empty, the `zip` object will yield 0 items -- are you _sure_ they all have something in them?

Comment: yes I'm sure, I'm able to get the data from the page and print them etc..  for sure those lists aren't empty

Comment: I suggest printing the length of that zip and all of those lists somewhere -- even if you can get data from one part of the page it's better to check all of them. If the debugger is skipping that block, it means the for loop is executed 0 times... so, your zip is empty.

Comment: I don't see any `zip` that has a `print` in it.  This doesn't strike me as a [mcve].  But you said the debugger doesn't even go into the for loop, which implies that there's nothing to iterate over. Stop on the line `output = []`, and inside the debugger, type `len(list(zip(titles, prices, tags, total_platforms)))`.  When that comes up empty, see what you get simply by typing `len(titles)`, then `len(prices)`, then `len(tags)`, then `len(total_platforms)`.  Then, update the question with this information.

Comment: i think that maybe something inside Pycharm was cached (somehow) - but I tried even restart and new env. Now it is working fine, but i did nothing just hit run and it worked :|

Comment: @Scott Mermelstein i just added clean code without many prints :)

Comment: I removed by mistake (in my version) the line with "total_platforms.append(platforms)" and Len was like you noticed 0 so zip could not iterate.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `zip` object is an iterator.
When you loop all elements of an iterator the object will be empty. Thus, you need replace the assignment to `resp` and use `print(info)`.

```
for info in zip(titles,prices, tags, total_platforms):
    print(info)
```

And the output:

```
('Dungeon Warfare 2', 'COL$ 22.500', ['Indie', 'Strategy', 'Tower Defense'], ['win', 'mac'])
('Kingdom Come: Deliverance – From the Ashes', 'COL$ 18.500', ['RPG', 'Action', 'Adventure'], ['win'])
('Red Faction Guerrilla Re-Mars-tered', 'COL$ 20.000', ['Destruction', 'Gore', 'Open World', 'Mars'], ['win'])
('Crash Bandicoot™ N. Sane Trilogy', 'COL$ 146.900', ['3D Platformer', 'Remake', 'Classic', 'Platformer'], ['win'])
('Ultimate Custom Night', 'Free', ['Free to Play', 'Horror', 'Difficult', 'Singleplayer'], ['win'])
('Event Pass: Sanhok', 'COL$ 29.200', ['Massively Multiplayer', 'Action', 'Violent', 'Adventure'], ['win'])
('LEGO® The Incredibles', 'COL$ 89.900', ['Action', 'Adventure', 'LEGO', 'Open World'], ['win'])
('Budget Cuts', 'COL$ 60.000', ['VR', 'Action', 'Indie', 'Adventure'], ['win', 'htcvive', 'oculusrift'])
('Wreckfest', 'COL$ 79.900', ['Racing', 'Destruction', 'Simulation', 'Physics'], ['win'])
('Jurassic World Evolution', 'COL$ 155.000', ['Building', 'Dinosaurs', 'Simulation', 'Management'], ['win'])
('Totally Accurate Battlegrounds', 'COL$ 9.900', ['Multiplayer', 'Funny', 'FPS', 'Action'], ['win'])
('Stoneshard: Prologue', 'Free', ['RPG', 'Adventure', 'Indie', 'Free to Play'], ['win', 'linux'])
('Vampyr', 'COL$ 112.000', ['Vampire', 'RPG', 'Action', 'Choices Matter'], ['win'])
('Dude, Stop', 'COL$ 25.000', ['Puzzle', 'Funny', 'Pixel Graphics', 'Comedy'], ['win'])
('Cultist Simulator', 'COL$ 31.000', ['Indie', 'Simulation', 'Card Game', 'Lovecraftian'], ['win', 'mac', 'linux'])
('Moonlighter', 'COL$ 31.000', ['Adventure', 'Pixel Graphics', 'Action', 'Rogue-like'], ['win', 'mac'])
```